# Building Hierarchy out of array using tables - PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm having difficulties with the following scenario, I have an array with categories, so categories can have child categories and the child categories can have child categories infinitely. Now what I'm trying to achieve is the following, but I just can't manage to achive this.

I have an array `$items` in the following structure

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Main Cat
            [id] => 29
            [parent_id] => 19
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Main Cat
            [id] => 17
            [parent_id] => 19
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Main Cat
            [id] => 20
            [parent_id] => 19
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Child Level 1
                            [id] => 21
                            [parent_id] => 20
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Child Level 1
                            [id] => 22
                            [parent_id] => 20
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => Child Level 2
                                            [id] => 27
                                            [parent_id] => 22
                                            [items] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [label] => Child Level 3
                                                            [id] => 28
                                                            [parent_id] => 27
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Child Level 1
                            [id] => 23
                            [parent_id] => 20
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Child Level 1
                            [id] => 24
                            [parent_id] => 20
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => Child Level 2
                                            [id] => 25
                                            [parent_id] => 24
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => Child Level 2
                                            [id] => 26
                                            [parent_id] => 24
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now I want the following array to display in a table with each child level indented, and if it should go one level up from Child Level 3 to Child Level 2 the indetation should reverse again.

Example

```
<table border="2" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Main Cat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Main Cat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Main Cat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin-left:20px;">Child Level 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin-left:20px;">Child Level 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin-left:40px;">Child Level 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin-left:60px;">Child Level 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin-left:20px;">Child Level 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin-left:20px;">Child Level 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin-left:40px;">Child Level 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin-left:40px;">Child Level 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My PHP code looks like this thus far,

```
public function renderCategoriesRecursive($items)
        {
                foreach($items as $item)
                {

                        $itemCount = count($item['items']);



                        echo CHtml::openTag('tr');
                            echo CHtml::openTag('td',array('class'=>$class));
                                echo $item['label'];
                            echo CHtml::closeTag('tr');
                        echo CHtml::closeTag('tr');


                        if(isset($item['items']) && $itemCount)
                        {

                                $this->renderCategoriesRecursive($item['items']);

                        }
                }
}
```

The variable **$items** contains the array above

Comment: Why not use JSON? That's what it is for. http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON... unless you mean for him to use AJAX and build it client side with Javascript templates.

Comment: You really ought to use nested lists for this, but I'll give you a solution below using tabling.

Comment: @runspired - Nested lists will do the job, but I need to have it in a tabular format, with borders etc, except if I can maybe style the list to look and act like tables, but I'm not sure if it might get a second column in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your own solution referenced the variable $class, so I've incorporated that too.  You really don't need to use CHtml (unless you do, but I've never seen such a case)

```
function renderItems( $array, $class, $indent = 0  ) {

    foreach( $items as $item) {
        echo '<tr><td class="'.$class.'">'.$item['label'].'</td></tr>';

        if( isset( $item['items'] && count( $item['items'] )
            renderItems($item['items'],$class,$indent+1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, actually it was really simply ;-) I was almost there ;-) Anyway I used your solution and it worked like a charm. Once again, thank you, saved me alot of time